# How to set private ip using json template in Azure resource manager portal?

Tags: json, azure

I am working Azure resource manager portal. i have create vm using json template. But the order of local ip address of vm is changed. `my requirement is 
10.0.0.4,10.0.0.5,10.0.0.6. 
but the output is
10.0.0.5, 10.0.0.6,10.0.0.4

i try to set private ip addresss using json

```
"properties": {
    "ipConfigurations": [
      {
        "name": "ipconfig1",
        "properties": {
          "privateIPAllocationMethod": "static",
          "PrivateIpAddress": [concat("10.0.0."), copyindex())],
          "copy": { 
                "name": "ipaddress", 
                "count": "["[variables('numberOfInstances')]"]" 
            }, 
          "subnet": {
            "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
          },
          "loadBalancerBackendAddressPools": [
            {
              "id": "[concat(variables('lbID'), '/backendAddressPools/BackendPool1')]"
            }
          ],
          "loadBalancerInboundNatRules": [
            {
              "id": "[concat(variables('lbID'),'/inboundNatRules/RDP-VM', copyindex())]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

but it throws json parsing exception. Anyone know how to set private ip address in json template?

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is with this:

```
"PrivateIpAddress": [concat("10.0.0."), copyindex())],
```

`copyindex()` gives you `0` with the first `VM`

And you cant use `10.0.0.0-3` in Azure.

```
Use copyindex(4)
```